# How to implement python custom function on dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, apply

I have a dictionary that contains 3 dataframes.

How do I implement a custom function  to each dataframes in the dictionary.

In simpler terms, I want to apply the function `find_outliers` as seen below

```
# User defined function : find_outliers
#(I)
from scipy import stats
outlier_threshold = 1.5   
ddof = 0   

def find_outliers(s: pd.Series):
    outlier_mask = np.abs(stats.zscore(s, ddof=ddof)) > outlier_threshold
    # replace boolean values with corresponding strings
    return ['background-color:blue' if val else '' for val in outlier_mask]
```

To the dictionary of dataframes `dict_of_dfs` below

```
#  the dataset 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = { 
         'col_A':['A_1001', 'A_1001', 'A_1001', 'A_1001', 'B_1002','B_1002','B_1002','B_1002','D_1003','D_1003','D_1003','D_1003'],
        'col_X':[110.21, 191.12, 190.21, 12.00, 245.09,4321.8,122.99,122.88,134.28,148.14,161.17,132.17],
        'col_Y':[100.22,199.10, 191.13,199.99, 255.19,131.22,144.27,192.21,7005.15,12.02,185.42,198.00],
        'col_Z':[140.29, 291.07, 390.22, 245.09, 4122.62,4004.52,395.17,149.19,288.91,123.93,913.17,1434.85]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df

#dictionary_of_dataframes
#(II)
dict_of_dfs=dict(tuple(df.groupby('col_A')))
```

and lastly, flag outliers in each `df` of the `dict_of_dfs`

```
# end goal is to have find/flag outliers in each `df` of the `dict_of_dfs`

#(III)
desired_cols = ['col_X','col_Y','col_Z'] 
dict_of_dfs.style.apply(find_outliers, subset=desired_cols)
```

summarily, I want to apply `I` to `II` and finally flag outliers in `III`
Thanks for your attempt. :)

Desired output should look like this, but for the three dataframes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but this is how I'd approach it, but you'll have to work out the details of the function because you have it written to receive a series rather a dataframe. Groupby apply() will send the subsets of rows and then you can perform the actions on that subset and return the result.

For consideration:

inside the function you may be able to handle all columns like so:

```
def find_outliers(x):
    for col in ['col_X','col_Y','col_Z']:
        outlier_mask = np.abs(stats.zscore(x[col], ddof=ddof)) > outlier_threshold
        x[col] = ['outlier' if val else '' for val in outlier_mask]
    return x


newdf = df.groupby('col_A').apply(find_outliers)

     col_A    col_X    col_Y col_Z
0   A_1001           outlier
1   A_1001
2   A_1001
3   A_1001  outlier
4   B_1002           outlier
5   B_1002  outlier
6   B_1002
7   B_1002
8   D_1003           outlier
9   D_1003
10  D_1003
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, however, I want to apply the `find_outliers` function to individual `df `  - `A_1001`  `B_1002`  and `D_1003`  instead of one large dataframe (hence the `dict_of_dfs`). In a nutshell, I want your approach replicated for three dfs, something along the lines of a `for loop`.

Comment: that' incorrect. groupby.apply() is applying the function to each subset as you describe. It just returns a full dataframe.

Comment: if the function is returning the wrong result for each subset, the function will need to be updated.

Comment: See the snapshot of your code, I want to split the dfs first and then find the outliers in each of the df.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you want to go the extra step of creating a dictionary and then looping the dictionary when my code does the same thing. Can you post what the solution should be? Is it a dictionary or dataframe? if you can post your expected output rather than describing it I may be able to help more. also to reiterate, the way you had your arguments setup before you can't pass a df as a series so it's not clear how you wanted the function applied to each column of the dataframe; which is why i loop through those columns. posting the expected outcome  the way you want will help.

Comment: end goal is to export 3 dfs as 3 sheets of a  `.xlsx` file. So I want to find outliers in each of the dataframe and not find outliers in one large dataframe.  I want to treat them as three separate dataframes

Comment: use dict_of_dfs=dict(tuple(newdf.groupby('col_A'))) using newdf at the end. This gives you the three outlier dfs where you can write them to excel as sheets

Comment: @ Jonathan Leon, one last thing, I want to highlight the outliers in the desired columns (check my code in `III` and the snapshot for the desired output for each dataframe). Any pointers? I'd appreciate if you add the revisions to your initial code. Thanks